# Solving equations with complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers

I am stuck on a problem;

Solve the equation

$x^{4} - 1 = 0$

I have only solved equations like this that were quadratic, so i'd really appreciate a hint about how to get started. I'm usually ok once I know where to start from.

Thanks!

Comment: As answerers and commenters have suggested, you should recognize this as a difference of squares. Once you do this, you’re on your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: Thanks, I can show this to be the case with the factor theorem, right?

Comment: @Jacobadtr You can show that to be the case by multiplying together the three terms.

Comment: Agreed, but that's working backwards in a sense. Suppose the factors weren't quite so obvious, the factor theorem seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)=(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1)$$

If $\displaystyle x^2+1=0, x^2=-1,x=\pm\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$

Comment: @GitGud, I could not determine where to stop

Comment: @GitGud, HINT & typo rectified

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a quartic; it's a quadratic in disguise.  Let $y=x^2$.  Then you have $$y^2 - 1 = 0$$  which you know how to solve for $y$.  Then $x = \pm\sqrt y$.

This method works on any polynomial whose terms are all of even degree.

Comment: Thanks, that's a handy way of looking at things - Hadn't thought of that before

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to notice that it is $(x^2)^2 - 1 = 0$, so $x^2 = \pm 1$. The rest is easy...

There is a nice formula for the quadratic equation, and there are (rather horrible) formulas for cubic and quartic (third and fourth degree) equations, for *general* higher degrees there are no formulas in terms of roots.

It is easy to see that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial, and $p(\alpha) = 0$, then $x - \alpha$ is a factor of $p(x)$ (just write down $p(x) - p(\alpha)$, and note that $x^k - \alpha^k$ is divisible by $x - \alpha$). The [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) helps weed out potential rational roots (and thus factors).